# Copied code not functioning the same (hangman)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a hangman script for a school project. I am stuck because one line does not function as it should, even though a copy works in a different script (also included down below). Here's the main code:

```
def random_word(word_list):
    global the_word
    the_word = random.choice(word_list)
    print (the_word)
    print (".")

def setup():
    global output_word
    size = 0   
    for c in the_word:
        size = size+1
    output_word = size*"_ "
    print (output_word, "("+str(size)+")")

def alter(output_word, guessed_letter, the_word):
    checkword = the_word
    print ("outputword:",output_word)
    previous = 0
    fully_checked = False
    while fully_checked == False:
        checkword = checkword[previous:]
        print ("..",checkword)
        if guessed_letter in checkword:
            the_index = (checkword.index(guessed_letter))
            print (output_word)
            print (the_index)
            print (guessed_letter)
  # Line below just won't work
            output_word= output_word.replace(output_word[the_index], guessed_letter)
            print (output_word)
            previous = the_index
            fully_checked = True

def guessing():
    global guessed_letter 
    guessed_letter = input("Enter a letter > ")    
    if guessed_letter in the_word:
        alter(output_word, guessed_letter, the_word)
```

So the line

```
output_word= output_word.replace(output_word[the_index], guessed_letter)
```

is supposed to print something like _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ (for the word swinging)
yet it prints

> _g_g_g_g_g_g_g

This is the full output:

```
costumed               #the_word
.
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  (8)   #output_word + size
Enter a letter > t
outputword: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
.. costumed #
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
3                      # the_index
t                      #guessed_letter
_t_t_t_t_t_t_t_t       #the new output_word
```

Yet in this different test code, everything works fine:

```
output_word = "thisworkstoo"
the_index = output_word.find("w")
guessed_letter = "X"
output_word= output_word.replace(output_word[the_index], guessed_letter)
print (output_word)
```

outputting:
    thisXorkstoo

Answer (score 0):

Replace replaces all of its first argument with the second argument. So saying

```
 output_word= output_word.replace(output_word[the_index], guessed_letter)
```

when output_word = `_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` will replace every single underscore with `guessed_letter`.

So I would to something like this:

```
output_word = list(output_word)
output_word[the_index] = guessed_letter
output_word = ''.join(i for i in output_word)
```

Shell example:

```
>>> output_word = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
>>> the_index = 3
>>> guessed_letter = "t"
>>> output_word = list(output_word)
>>> output_word[the_index] = guessed_letter
>>> output_word = ''.join(i for i in output_word)
>>> output_word
'_ _t_ _ _ _ _ _'
```

An even better way to do this would be:

```
output_word = output_word[:the_index] + guessed_letter + output_word[the_index+1]
```

Comment: Will this replace all instances of a letter in the word?

Comment: do you need it to? I added a shell example to show you what it does.